# Ringtone set from a file reverts to default after reboot

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, settings, 5.1-lollipop, ringtone

When I set a ringtone from a file ("More ringtones"), after reboot it reverts to the default ringtone on the pre-set list. How to fix this?

When I choose a ringtone from the pre-set list, it does stay (does not revert to the default one).

The file I select is in `Phone storage/Ringtones`.

I tried Zedge to set a downloaded ringtone, same effect: after reboot, it resets to the default one. As a workaround, maybe there is an app that would check the ringtone after reboot and set its own one if it has reverted to the default?

Android 5.1 kernel 3.10.65, model Polariod P5025A, not rooted.

The phone has other issues, such as after reboot some downloaded apps (not always, but Opera almost always) disappear from the desktop, so that I have to bring their icons to the desktop again. The downloaded apps are on SD card (probably that's why), but my old phone (Android 4.4 on Samsung, a great deal better than 5.1) did not have any of these problems.

Comment: Is the new phone Samsung as well?

Comment: @WrichikBasu The ringtone I set is some .mp3 file which I found somewhere in Internet. (Motivation: this high-pitch beep-beep sound is loud to be well heard from another room and is clearly identified as a sound of a device. All the pre-set ringtones on this phone are songs or melodies, of low volume -- some are, say, noise of wind and bird's songs (!!), which are completely lost in a noisy environment with music from the street and other natural sounds.)

Comment: @WrichikBasu Ah sorry I misread the question. No, the new phone is Polaroid.

Comment: You  could have bought Samsung, as Samsung doesn't have these problems. Moreover, almost all Samsung devices on 5.0 android have been upgraded to 6.0 by official software update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps such as [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) can definitely set the ringtone after device boot.

- Profile: Event → System → Device Boot
- Task: Audio → Default Ringtone:

  - Type: Ringer
  - Sound: tap lens icon → choose File Manger app -> select your sound file.

File Manager app should be such app which allow a sound file to be selected as a ringtone. I'm aware of [Solid File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2) and [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) providing such feature.

If you don't get the option to use the File Manager app, then clear the defaults of Media Server from **Settings → Apps → All apps** (or three dots line **→ Show system) → Media Server → Open by default → Clear defaults**.

Comment: Tasker did the trick. No need to install the intrusive ES File Explorer, I could directly set the ringtone using the built-in interface with the action "set ringtone", not "choose File Manager".